# List all potential paths between linked turtles

Tags: netlogo

Is there an easy way using the NW extension to generate all possible paths without loops (not just the shortest using path-to) between a pair of linked turtles?

Comment: What have you already tried?  How would you handle loops in paths?

Comment: don't understand all the close votes on this — seems like a pretty clear question to me

Comment: This is a perfectly sensible question. As hardmath implies, there are an infinite number of paths between turtles if any loops are present. I take the question as "all paths between turtles that contain know cycles".

Anyway, the NW extension doesn't support this I'm afraid. It will give you all of the shortest paths (it randomly chooses one each time you call `path-to`). Non-shortest paths are computationally intense to find (they require a complete network traversal) and usually not very useful. Feel free to request the feature though: https://github.com/NetLogo/NW-Extension/issues/new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that this question is open again, I'm just reposting my comment as an answer:

For an undirected network, there are infinite number of paths between two turtles if there are any loops anywhere in the network. Because of that, I'll assume you meant "all paths between turtles that do not contain loops".

The NW extension doesn't support this I'm afraid. It will give you all of the shortest paths (it randomly chooses one each time you call path-to). Non-shortest paths are computationally intense to find (or rather, finding all of them is intense because there are so many) and usually not very useful. Feel free to request the feature though: https://github.com/NetLogo/NW-Extension/issues/new.

Note that finding a single, random non-shortest path is super easy, especially if you don't mind loops: just walk the network, picking random links each time, until you arrive at your destination. To eliminate loops, just make sure you haven't visited that node yet. That is:

```
to-report random-path-to [ target ]
  let path (list self)
  while [ last path != target ] [
    set path lput [one-of link-neighbors] of (last path) path
  ]
  report path
end
```

Without loops:

```
to-report random-path-to [ target ]
  let path (list self)
  while [ last path != target ] [
    set path lput [one-of link-neighbors with [ not member? self path ] ] of (last path) path
  ]
  report path
end
```

I didn't test either of these, but they should at least point you in the right direction. Also, they should be modified to take into account situations in which turtles aren't connected.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't thought this completely through but it's partially right and I hope it might inspire a solution. Imagine you are trying to find all the paths between nodeA and nodeB. What you could do is run through all possible nodeC (that is, all nodes that aren't A or B) and find the shortest path between nodeA and nodeC, and between nodeC and nodeB. Then the path between A and B is the combination of the two paths. You would then have to throw out paths that backtrack but I think that can be done by rejecting the proposed path if any node (apart from C) appears in both parts. There would also be some duplicates that need to be thrown out and there are also additional paths that are, for eaxmple, the shortest between A and C, then C and D, then D and B.